# How to convert DWORDLONG to a char *?

Tags: c++, string, dword

```
    res = pRecord->Usn ;
    char sres[1024];
    strcpy(sres,"");
    ltoa(res,sres, 10);
```

I have this variable res, which is of type `DWORDLONG`, and I am trying to convert it into a string so that I can insert it into the database.

Also, how would I convert it back. Is there a equivalent of ltoa, or do you have to write the logic yourself?

Comment: This is one reason I dislike the practice of defining your own types for basics. I forget what a DWORDLONG *really* is.

Comment: @sje397: overloading comes to the rescue here ;)

Comment: Its a 64 bit unsigned integer typedef ULONGLONG DWORDLONG;

Comment: @DeadMG, sorry about that, how do I go about doing it the right way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(res);
```

or

```
std::ostringstream o;
o << res;
o.str();
```

or in C++11

```
std::to_string(res);
```

For going back in C++11 you would use

```
res=std::stoull(str)
```

or in C  *shiver *

```
char* end;
res=strtoull(str.c_str(),&end,10);
```

Comment: Yay - by the way, I never use the optional pointer for `strtoull()`. I guess you could use if for error checking...

Comment: @KerrekSB: Indeed, that what it is for, and I personally always use it, since in >90% of all cases I get the data from unreliable sources (== user input).